# How to access shared resource from a Web Service?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I read that in Java EE a Web Service will spawn a thread for every request, so I don't have to thread blocking operations (e.g. database queries) myself.

How would I properly access a shared resource from such thread-dispatched method?

e.g. if I have a `SessionManager` which contains a map of `User` objects and a `loginUser()` method to allow logins outside of a JSF context, how would I prevent race conditions? Do I just use mutexes, or does JavaEE provide a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE doesn't provide you with any solution for resource contention over your own resources; but Java does.

For your case, using a `ConcurrentHashMap` may solve most of your problems. A `ConcurrentHashMap` will protect you against cases in which two threads update the `Map` in exactly the same time (which, in a `HashMap`, is likely to throw an exception). It offers you the same methods from the `Map` interface as `HashMap`, plus a few useful methods from the `ConcurrentMap` interface (such as `replace` and `putIfAbsent`). For most needs, this option is sufficient.

Having said that, sometimes, you might need to use the `synchronized` keyword even if you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap`. For example, consider a case when you'd like to put two items into the `Map`, but it's extremely important to you that, while the current thread is issuing the two `put`s, *no other thread will `get` or `put` from the Map*. In other words, `ConcurrentHashMap` only isolates access for each call individually; for cases when you need the isolation to span multiple calls, use `synchronized`.

**EDIT** following @Arjan's comment: if you're using JavaEE 6.0 onwards, you can use `@Singleton` in combination with `@Lock` to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: >Java EE doesn't provide you with any solution - Uhm, what about @Singleton and @Lock? See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Map you can use Concuurent HashMap..
Java won't deal with something you want to create manuallylike webserver that will hold key value pairs of users and something like sessionId after login, Usually the Server can do it..

Anyway this is not a problem.. This ConcurrentHashMap is perfect for those situations, It Thread-Safe, And it is higher performance than HashTable(They work diffrently)

HashTable lock the Map
ConcurrentHashMap lock evrey item by himself.. So 2 threads can use the map together if they are not touching the same nodes..

You should read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Hope that helps

Comment: We want to allow logons from a native Android App, so we cannot use @ SessionScoped @ ManagedBeans.

Comment: Got you.. You can generate your own sessionId, Once the user is doing login you save userId with your SessionId in this map. 
In case the user logout you remove from map... And in case the user closed the application not in proper way, You can set timer and check if the last action has been maid befoer 15 minutes so you automatically remove this user from login map

Comment: Please remmember that if you have some clustered enviorment.. This won't be the best solution, You need to read a little bit about redis..They provide cache capablities.. Check this link 
http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: I understand, but it won't be that big of a system. Thanks.