# Migrating CORBA Application to Modern Java technologies (Rest/SOAP/EJB)

Tags: java, ejb, rmi, corba, ws-transaction

I have a requirement to migrate a legacy CORBA system to any latest java technology. The main problem I am facing is to provide long lived transaction(db)  in the proposed system. Currently the client(Swing App) retain the CORBA service object and perform multiple db txn before actually committing/rolling back all the txn. Service layer keep the state of connection object through out to  complete transaction.

I wanted to reproduce this mechanism in my new system(REST/WS)  so that either Swing client/Web(future) can work in the same as is.

Eg:

```
try {
    service1.updateXXData(); // --> insert in to table XX
    service2.updateUUData()  //--> insert in to table UU
    service1.updateZZData(); // --> insert in to table ZZ
    service2.updateAAData(); // --> insert in to table AA
  
    service1.commit(); //  con.commmit();
    service2.commit(); // con.commmit();

}
exception(){
    service1.rollback(); // con.rollback();
    service2.rollback(); // con.rollback();
}
```

Now  I wanted to migrate CORBA to any modern technolgy, but still I am at large to find a solution for this. ( the concern is client do not want to make any change to service layer or db layer) , they just wanted to remove CORBA.

A couple of options available for me are:

1. Migrate CORBA to RMI --> so that changes required to current system are minimal, but transaction management,connection pooling, retaining state need to do myself;
2. Migrate CORBA to Stateful EJB --> Compare RMI more changes required, but better since I can use container managed connection pooling, maintain state in a better way;
3. Migrate CORBA to Stateful Webservice(SOAP) --> More futuristic, but lot of changes required  - How ever I can convert IDL to WSDL, and delegate the call to implementation layer;
4. Migrate CORBA to REST --> Most desired if possible - but the amount of time required to migrate is huge , Code changes would require from UI layer to service layer.

Comment: Not sure if this is a valuable hint for you but you can try to investigate http://narayana.io project. In general it supports WS, REST and Compensation txn.
Some examples e.g. at https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart

Answer (score 5):

The order in which I would choose the options, from best to worst, would be 4, 3, 2, and 1, however I'd avoid stateful beans or services if humanly possible to do so.

I'll go over the implementation details of what you'll have to do in detail.

For any of these solutions, you'll have to use [XA-compliant data sources and transactions](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/resources/tutorials/understanding-jta/distributed-transactions-and-the-transaction-manager) so you can guarantee ACID compliance, [preferably from an application server so you don't have to generate the transaction yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).  This should be an improvement from your existing application as it almost certainly can't guarantee that, but be advised that in my experience, people put loads of hacks in to essentially reinvent JTA, so watch out for that.

For 4, you'll want to use [container-managed transactions with XA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgs/index.html).  You might do this by [injecting a `@PersistenceContext` backed by a JTA connection](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/).  Yes, this costs a ton of time, testing, and effort, but it has two bonuses: First, moving to the web will be a lot easier, and it sounds like that time is coming.  Second, those that come after you are more likely to be well-versed in newer web service technologies than bare CORBA and RMI.

For 3, you'll also want to use [container-managed transactions with XA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgs/index.html).  SOAP would not be my first choice as it uses very verbose messages and REST is more popular, but it could be done.  If it's stateful, though, you'll have to use [bean-managed transactions instead](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch18.html) and then [hang on to resources across web service calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922580/how-to-access-shared-resource-from-a-web-service).  This is dangerous, as it could potentially deadlock the whole system.

For 2, you can go two ways, either using [container-managed transactions with XA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgs/index.html) by using a [stateless session facade for a stateful EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636764/why-use-facade-pattern-for-ejb-session-bean).  You can [use a client JAR for your EJB](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t) and package that with the Swing app.  Using the stateless facade is preferable, as it will reduce the load on your application server.  Keep in mind that you can generate [web services from stateless EJB beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html#bnbot) too, essentially turning this into #3.

For 1... well, good luck.  It is possible to [use RMI to interface with EJB's](http://www.darwinsys.com/java/rmi/), and generate your own stub and tie, though this is not recommended, and for very good reason.  This hasn't been a popular practice for years, may require the stubs and ties to be regenerated periodically, and may require an understanding of the low-level functions of the app server.  Even here, you'll want XA transactions.  You don't want to handle the transaction management yourself, if possible.

Ultimately, as I'm sure everyone will agree, the choice is yours on what to do, and there's no "right" or "wrong" way, despite the opinions stated above.  If it were me (and it's not), I'd ask two important questions of myself and my customer:

1. Is this for a contract or temporary engagement, and if so what is the term?  Do I get first pick at another contract for this same system later when they want additional updates?  (In other words, how much money am I going to get out of this vs. how much time am I spending?  If it's going to be a long term, then I would go with 4 or 3, otherwise 3 or 2 would be better.)
2. Why get rid of CORBA?  "Because it's old" is an honest answer, but what's the impetus of getting rid of the "old hotness?"  Do they plan on expanding usage of this system in the future?  Is there some license about to expire and they just want to keep the lights on?  Is it because they don't want to dump this on some younger programmer who might not know how to deal with low-level stuff like this?  What do you want the system to do in two years, five years, or longer?

(OK, so that's more than two questions :D)